# Get string from textview at a particular position in recyclerview

Tags: android, textview, android-recyclerview

I am already aware of the recycler position. What is need is to get the text from the TextView at a particular position of recyclerview!

ie, a string from textview in a recyclerview at position = x

Comment: When you setThe Textview's value , why don't you save the value in a list . Also, provide some code so that we can help you .

Comment: I need the text after it has been set!

Comment: Can you show your code what you've tried?

Comment: I guess my issue is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the view holder is for recyclerview is : viewHolder

In the onclick listener I used,

```
viewHolder.myTextView.getText().toString();
```

(The onclick listener returns the postition also)

Answer (score 0):

hey you can manage the click of the single view in the recyler view and on click you can get the value of the textview by simply using

```
textview.getText().toString();
```

If needed you can also use the getadapter position , to get the position on which you just clicked.

Thanks, it might help you.